# Regext to match any substring longer than 2 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

regex-pattern-to-match-any-substring-matching exact characters longer-than-two-characters-from-a-provided input,where ever exact string matches

Only `pot` or `potato` should be highlighted, instead of `ota` or `ot`, when user type `pota` and click search button.

[image]

Please find code below where matched string is highlighted.

```
// Core function
function buildRegexFor(find) {
    var regexStr = find.substr(0,3);
    for (var i = 1; i < find.length - 2; i++) {
        regexStr = '(' + regexStr + find.substr(i+2,1) + '?|' + find.substr(i,3) + ')';
    }
    return regexStr;
}

// Handle button click event 
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
    // (1) read input
    var find = document.querySelector('input').value;
    var str = document.querySelector('textarea').value;

    // (2) build regular expression using above function
    var regexStr = buildRegexFor(find);

    // (3) apply regular expression to text and highlight all found instances   
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(regexStr, 'g'), "<strong class='boldtxt'>$1</strong>");

    // (4) output
    document.querySelector('span').textContent = regexStr;
    document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = str;
};
```

consider "meter & parameter" as one string, if type meter in input box and click search button. meter should be highlighted as well as meter in parameter should highlight.Thanks in advance

Comment: No, i took screenshot and attached

Comment: Please **look** at your question before posting it, if you can't see the image, or any reference to it, neither can anyone else; An image of a js fiddle is much less useful than a link to the fiddle itself. I've fixed the markup so the image is visible, but your question is unclear.

Comment: what the hell is that first sentence?

Comment: Thank you for fixing markup.  var find ="meter"; var str = "meter & parameter";

Comment: In above variable str only meter should be highlighted in both meter & parameter thorugh regex. do you want me to share js fiddle link?

Comment: you just asked this question again **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979633/consider-meter-parameter-as-one-string-meter-should-be-highlighted-as-well)**

Comment: yes, Could you please help me in finding solution.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chethu518/1zxv3hLm/ please find js fiddle link, Search term is Pota in input box, after click find button. only content with pot or pota should be highlighted. whereas ota from botanic should not be highlighted. Could anyone please help me. Kindly let me know if additional information required or question should be edited.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is set to go from i = 1, while i is less than find.length-2.  find.length is 4.  4-2 is 2.  So your for loop is set to go from i = 1 while i is less than 2.  In other words, it's operating exactly once.  I have no idea what you thought that for loop was going to do, but I'm betting that isn't it.

Prior to the for loop, regextr is set equal to the string `pot` (the first three characters of the find string.  The first (and only) time through the for loop, it is set to a new value:  the left paren, the existing value (pot), the fourth character of find (a), the question mark, the vertical bar, and three characters from find starting with the second.  Put those together, and your regextr comes out to:

`(pota?|ota)`

That RegEx says to find either the string "pota" (with the a being optional, so "pot" also works) or the string "ota".  So any instances of pota, pot, or ota will be found and highlighted.

If you just wanted "pota?", just eliminate the right half of that line inside the for loop.  Better yet, replace the entire subroutine with just a line that appends the ? character to the find string.